# remove an animation iteration event listener to animated child node

Tags: javascript, css, animation, event-handling, removeeventlistener

**SCENARIO**:
I have a top/parent `<div>` that has an infinite CSS animation on it.
It also has some `<div>` as sub/child nodes and some (one or more) might have as well an infinite CSS animation on them.

**HTML excerpt**:

```
<div id="top_div" class="anim1">
 <div class="anim2">some more animated contents here</div>
 <div>(this gets animated by effect of its parent, of course)</div>
</div>
```

**CSS excerpt** (just to have an idea):

```
#top_div.anim1 {animation: swinging .5s linear infinite alternate forwards;}
@keyframes swinging {to{transform:rotate(20deg);}}
.anim2 {/*...another different infinite animation here...*/}
```

NOW THE QUESTION IS:
I added an event handler 'cause I need to do something every parent animation iteration ... and I only need that one! The problem is the event triggers even when child nodes infinite animations iterate...
So, of course, I decided to check if the event is related to the parent node's animation or not but *I also would like to try to remove somehow the event handler from the child nodes*.
I'm using the following **JavaSript code**:

```
function anim123(e){
  if (e.target == top_div && e.animationName == "swinging") do_what_I_need();
  else e.target.removeEventListener("animationiteration", anim123);
}
top_div.addEventListener("animationiteration",anim123);
```

The `else` branch doesn't seem having any effect there, the event continues to trigger when child nodes animation iterates... Can you tell me what's wrong with it?

Maybe I guess I can't remove something that "doesn't really exist"? (and, indeed, the child nodes don't really has an event handler attached, they kinda "inherit" that from their parent so...) Is it even possible to remove those "inherited" child event listeners/handler or should I be content with the simple "not doing" the `do_what_I_need()` when they trigger?

Oh, and would it ever be possible to attach the `animationiteration` event handler to the parent node only and avoid it to be "inherited" by its child nodes (so that I can be sure only its animation will trigger and I wouldn't even need to care about child nodes in the handler code)?

Thank you for your help guys

Comment: try adding `e.stopPropagation();` at the top of `anim123`

Comment: I don't see any problem https://jsfiddle.net/ws1ef793/1/ check the console

Comment: @evgenifotia I tried `e.stopPropagation();` but it has no effect in this scenario... (That doesn't surprises me tbh)

Comment: you can even delete `else e.target.removeEventListener("animationiteration", anim123);` and it will still works

Comment: @evgenifotia I know I could delete the `else` branch in my code 'cause that has no desired effect but my question is, in fact: **how do I make it work on removing the child event triggering**? (P.S. In your fiddle you only logged the parent div event, try modify it like this: `else { e.target.removeEventListener("animationiteration", anim123); 
console.log(e.target.className);
}` and you'll notice the child still triggers even after it... I would like to avoid this to happen...) P.P.S. thanks for your replies and your help :)

Comment: I understand now but sorry I can't set `e.bubbles` to `false`. maybe you would like to add a bounty